# $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{r=0}^{k} \binom{s}{k}\binom{k}{r} C_{n,r}=\sum_{k=r}^{n} \sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{s}{k}\binom{k}{r} C_{n,r}$?

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a way to check how the indices switch?

$C_{n,s}$ is the potential partition polynomial

$$
C_{n,s}=\sum \frac{n!}{k_1!(1!)^{k_1}...{k_n}!(n!)^{k_n}}(s)_k {x_1}^{k_1}...{x_n}^{k_n}
$$

The book skips this part and i've tried using $\binom{s}{k}\binom{k}{r}=\binom{s}{r}\binom{s-r}{k-r}$, but i'm not sure what makes the title equality in the indices?

Comment: The second expression makes no sense because the index $r$ of the inner sum appears in the outer sum i.e. before it is defined. If you change the order of sums then both sides use the same index set $\{(k,r)~:~0\leq r\leq k\leq n\}$ which explains the equality (regardless of what $C$ is and of what is inside the sums).

Comment: Could you provide a proof of that? I'm not sure how the indices are changed or if binomial identities are used

Comment: @BaklavaGain: There’s nothing to prove: if you sum over the same finite set of indices, you get the same sum no matter the order in which you do the summing. Are you familiar with changing the order of integration? What you need to do here is similar to what you do when you convert $\int_0^a\int_0^xf(x,y)\,dydx$ to $\int_0^a\int_y^af(x,y)\,dxdy$.